# Python logger not writing to file anymore

Tags: python, logging

I have a function that should print in terminal a message and append it to file. It uses Python Logger.

```py
@staticmethod
def Log(iv_level, iv_style, iv_domain, iv_number, *args):
    """
    Log messages
    """
    # Do not log message with insufficient level
    lv_log_level = Logger.LOG_LEVEL
    if lv_log_level > iv_level:
        return
    if iv_level == Logger.VERBOSE:
        iv_level = logging.DEBUG

    # Default output format
    try:
       logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/logs.log', level=lv_log_level, format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s')
    except:
       logging.basicConfig(filename='server/logs/logs.log', level=lv_log_level, format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s')
    lo_logger = logging.getLogger(iv_domain)

    # Fetch message from database and log it to file
    # Log message are always in English
    ev_message = FrontendMessage.get(iv_domain, iv_number, *args, lang="en", buffer=True)['short_text']
    # Log into file only if environment is local
    if settings.SERVER_ENVIRONMENT == "-local":
        if platform == "win32" :
            # ! When I execute it pass thought the next step but doesn't write in logs/logs.log as it should
            lo_logger.log(iv_level, iv_domain + ' | ' + str(iv_number) + ' | ' + ev_message.replace('\U0001f4be','').replace('\U0001f3e2','').replace('\U0001f538','').replace('\U0001f535','').replace('\U0001f50e','').replace('\u2705','').replace('\u200d','').replace('\U0001F469','').replace('\u2695','').replace('\uFE0F','').replace('\U0001f464',''), extra={
                "message_info": {
                    "domain": iv_domain,
                    "number": iv_number
                }
            })
        else:
            lo_logger.log(iv_level, iv_domain + ' | ' + str(iv_number) + ' | ' + ev_message, extra={
                "message_info": {
                    "domain": iv_domain,
                    "number": iv_number
                }
            })

    # Print message
    print(stylize(ev_message, iv_style))
    return ev_message
```

When I execute this code, it works fine and pass thought lo_logger.log(...) but nothing is written in file. I can't find or understand what I missed...